# Dygraph Unix Timestamp

Tags: javascript, date, unix, charts, timestamp

I am trying to visualize tons of data using dygraph. So far I am really amazed with the library but I can not get it to work with unix timestamps properly. I want the date displayed in a human readable format. I took their example from their page and pasted some of my data into it:

```
g = new Dygraph(
    document.getElementById("graph"),
    // For possible data formats, see http://dygraphs.com/data.html
    // The x-values could also be dates, e.g. "2012/03/15"
    `X,Y1
    1532163461391,19.179613
    1532163462391,20.12414
    1532163463391,20.370108`,
    {
      // options go here. See http://dygraphs.com/options.html
      legend: 'always',
      animatedZooms: true,
      title: 'dygraphs chart template',
       axis : {
                        x : {
                            valueFormatter: Dygraph.dateString_,
                            ticker: Dygraph.dateTicker
                        }
       }
    });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/34z6sp2L/1/

Answer (score 1):

You just have a small typo. Change `axis` to `axes`.